# Adding android sdk location to the PATH

Tags: android, bash

I'm trying to add the location of Android sdk to my path on a mac.
Here's my $PATH

```
/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/tools/:/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

However when I try to run ./android, I keep getting the error

```
-bash: ./android: No such file or directory.
```

Evidently it's not finding the path correctly. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run it with :

```
android
```

not `./android`

Comment: @Jumper,Please accept as ans if it resolve ur problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the SDK to the path is usually adding the platform-tools folder in the $PATH var so you can access adb without navigating to the where the binary is.

In my system I created a `.profile` in my home folder. This file is ran whenever you open a new terminal.

In mine I have :

```
export $PATH="$PATH:<path_to_platform_tools>"
```

Make sure you make this script executable with

```
chmod +x .profile
```